# Best NN for image pattern recognition without classifier

Tags: keras, tensorflow, image-recognition

For images like this

[image]

[image]

[image]

I'm trying to split up the cells (the different rectangles). The cells, can vary in size, brightness and so forth.

I tried multiple ways using OpenCV for about 5 days, I almost got it working, but there are always edge-cases for which it fails, so I want to give it a shot using ML.

I believe the best way to do so, is to find the intersection patterns, upon which I can know the boundaries of the cells using a Mask R-CNN trained over images like this:

[image]
[image]
[image]
etc..

Once the position of these objects is known (the crossing point) I can create a grid to split up the cells, a 70-80% accuracy would be enough to generate the grid.

Although, most of the R-CNN includes a classification layer, which I don't given I try to detect a multitude of single objects.

Which type of NN should I be using for that purpose?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fImlO.jpg)

Comment: I confess that I don’t totally understand what you’re asking, but ConvNets don’t have to be used as classifiers, even if that is the most common application.

Comment: @Dave could you point out what is unclear so that I can edit the question?

Comment: Setting aside the issues with using accuracy as a performance metric, why are you using accuracy for a task that isn’t classification?

Comment: @Dave what would be the alternative ?

Comment: @Dave from my beginner understanding, I can use the accuracy to have a level of confidence on detection, then set a threshold whether a specific point is recognized or not